# Can we create a shorcode to move next page?

Tags: shortcode

Could you please help me understand if we can create a shortcode to move on to next page.

For example, I will have a short code "GO_NEXT_PAGE", which will help me to go from post mydomain.com/test_post to mydomain.com/test_post/2.

For example you can check [this page](http://amexing.com/identify-freedom-fighters). I will click on "SHOW_ME_ANSWER" and this will take me to [this page](http://amexing.com/identify-freedom-fighters/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you want to do, but it looks like you're looking for the built in `<!--nextpage-->` shortcode, which allows you to cut a post in two or even more pieces.

If you control your theme you can [style `wp_link_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links) to change the link from the default 'next page' to something like 'Show me the answer'. Or you can [use a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_pages/) to do even more complicated stuff.

Alternatively, there's all kinds of plugins, of course.

Comment: Thanks,But that is not I want. I want to a short code, which will help me to move next page. I am aware about <!--nextpage--> but only at some instance i want to use short code "SHOW_ME_THE ANSWER" for visitors to move the next page. at any other instance they can still navigate to different sub pages 2/3/4/5 and so on...

Comment: The example you give links to `/2/`, which is the same as subpage 2 you are referring to. If you only want a different name of the link in some cases, use a filter.

Comment: I am using subpages for many other purposes not every time subpage/2/ has the answer. I want to use short code 'SHOW_ME_ANSWER' only when the next page has answer. I am already asking user to move to next page to see the answer and giving link of subpage manually, however i wanted to make it shortcode if possible so that i jst type the shortcode and upon cliking on that by user will move them to next page to show answer.